# Discord Reaction Role doesn't attribute roles

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I'm trying to create a Discord Reaction Role and I would like to assign a role when a user clicks on the message emoji in the channel. Here is my code, it doesn't work from messageReactionAdd :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { token } = require('./config.json');

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot opérationnel");
});

// Permet d'ajouter une réaction à un message

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.content === '!roles') {
        const reactionEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'FR');
        message.react(reactionEmoji);
       // console.log(reactionEmoji)
    }
});

client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
    if (user.bot) return;
    console.log("Réaction ajoutée");
    if (reaction.message.id === "1036663050276704346") { //ID du message
        console.log(reaction.message.id);
        if (reaction.emoji.name === message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'FR')) {
            var member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id); // Va récuperer le membre du serveur 
            member.roles.add("1036583426620399647").then(mbr => { // Assigne le role avec ID France
                console.log("Role attribué avec succès pour" + mbr.displayName);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("Le role n'a pas pu etre attribué :" + err);
            });
        }
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to provide intents: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents

Answer (score 0):

Activate the SERVER MEMBERS INTENT and the MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT from the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).